# Trying to update nested / subdocument in Express

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose

I have a Mongoose model that has nested array and a subdocument.

I seem to be ok when posting to the object arrays/subdocument, but I'm having trouble with the .put

I hard coded the params for testing, just in case they were not coming in from PostMan for some reason.

The result I get from the above code is an empty array!

So I'm getting the right record and it creates the "phone" array, but does not populate.

```
.put(function(req, res){
  Member.find({'_id':req.params.id}, function(err, member){
    if(err)
      res.send(err);

      member.phone.push({
        number: "78787878787",
        phoneType: 2
      })


    member.save(function(err){
      if(err)
        res.send(err);
      res.json(member);
    });
  });
});
```

I want to have an endpoint that simply adds another "phone" record.

Here is my model:

```
//DEPENDENCIES
var mongoose = require('mongoose');


var contactSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  name:{type:String},
  age:{type:Number}
});

var phoneSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  number:{ type: String },
  phoneType:{ type: Number }
})

var memberSchema = new mongoose.Schema({

  firstname: {
    type: String
  },
  lastname: {
    type: String
  },
  phone:[phoneSchema],
  contacts:[contactSchema]

  });

//RETURN MODEL

module.exports = mongoose.model('member', memberSchema);
```

Now when I run my code I get the following undefined for "members":

```
{ id: '587bcbffe64e9f28a6894dd7' }
[ { _id: 587bcbffe64e9f28a6894dd7,
    lastname: 'Stanley',
    firstname: 'Dave',
    __v: 0,
    contacts: [ [Object] ],
    phone: [] } ]
events.js:154
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

TypeError: Cannot read property 'push' of undefined
```

Comment: do you want 2 objects inside phone array? One having number and another having phoneType?

Comment: Hi Ravi, actually no. Just a single object with both values. I'll fix that.

Comment: Any thoughts on why it's not saving the values to phone?

Comment: CAn you do `console.log(req.params)` and tell me what is the result?

Comment: Hi Ravi, take a look at my changes. I did find that there was an issue with my route and I've now changed that. As far as updating, for some reason, I'm getting a message that my "member" object is undefined, when I try to push a new phone contact using "member.phone".

Comment: are you sure `req.params.id` exist? I mean is that correct?

Comment: Yes. The last snippet of code is from the console.log. It returns the main object, but breaks at the phone array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`find` returns an array of documents, not just one document. Thats is why it is giving error when you are trying to do `member.phone`.

Use `findOne` instead of `find` as you are `querying` by `_id`, it will `return` only one matched document or `null`(if its not present), so its a better choice than `find`.

Also, its better to check if the `result` is `null` or not. `member` will be `null` if no such `_id` is present.

```
Member.findOne({'_id':req.params.id}, function(err, member){
    if(err)
      res.send(err);
    else if(member!=null)
    {
        member.phone.push({
            number: "78787878787",
            phoneType: 2
        });
        member.save(function(err){...});
    }
});
```

If you are keen on using `find`. Use `member[0]` (first element) instead of `member`.

```
Member.find({'_id':req.params.id}, function(err, member){
    if(err)
      res.send(err);
    else if(member.length!=0)
    {
        member[0].phone.push({
            number: "78787878787",
            phoneType: 2
        });

        member[0].save(function(err){...});
    }
});
```

Hope that helps you.

Comment: Done. If you have a sec, there is a follow up I posted to help me understand deleting a subdocument item: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41682734/removing-a-child-element-in-subdocument-not-working.

Comment: Yeah. Thanks, Ravi!

Comment: If someone is helping you, you should appreciate it by upvoting the answer bro. This keeps them motivated to help others and give other answers to

Comment: Hi Ravi. I checked your answer. Am I missing something? Is there another step to upvote?

Comment: No, i meant upvote, thats it. Right check is marking for correct answer and upvoting are two different things. but its fine. Glad i could help you solve your problem. I was giving your other question answer too but my the time i wrote it, you had already solved it. But i have one suggeston for you for that question. you should use `findOneAndUpdate` instead of `find` and then removing and saving again. This saves you with dealing with another callback.

Comment: Awesome. Thanks again Ravi! You have been very generous with your help.